# Remove Connected user in Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote-desktop, session

How Can I remove/clear all RDC logged users in a windows machine?

Note: I have an Administrator RDC account

**EDIT:**
I'm working with Windows Server 2003

Everytime I want to connect remotely, It prompts that the terminal server has exceeded the maximum number of allowed connections. I tried to clear all sessions using qwinsta/quser and reset session method, but ended up with nothing.

Comment: You should provide more information, like which Windows version and a concrete use case.

Comment: @Simon See my edit above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To connect to the Terminal Server despite the limited connections, what you can do is to connect to the server with the /admin switch. To do this, launch `mstsc` as follows:

```
mstsc /v:n.n.n.n /admin
```

Replace `n.n.n.n` with the IP of the server and you’re good to go. Once connected to the server, use **Task Manager** to log off the sessions that are no longer used.

To do this, select the session you wish to disconnect and click **Logoff**. Note that this will effectively log off the session and closes all windows still open in that session!

Once these steps have been completed, log your current session off and you should be able to reconnect to the server without using the /admin switch.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the often-repeated solution of using `mstsc` with the `/admin` switch doesn't work, we need an actual solution.

## The actual solution

We have to remotely log a user off. You can do this using the `reset` command. In this example the server we want to kick someone off of is called `tyderian`

- Establish a connection to the server

  ```
  C:\Users\ian>net use /user:ian \\tyderian
  The command completed successfully.
  ```
- List the existing sessions on the server

  ```
  C:\Users\ian>query session /server:tyderian
   SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
   console           superdude                 0  Active  wdcon
   rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen  rdpwd
   rdp-tcp#61        Ian                       2  Active  rdpwd
                     superdude                 5  Disc    rdpwd
  ```
- Pick someone to boot off the server, and boot them off the server

  ```
  C:\Users\ian>reset session 5 /server:tyderian
  ```

And viola, you can now RDP to `tyderian`.